problem with extended chess pgn format (including time)
I have chess games in pgn format enriched with times (eg.: 1. Nf3 {[%clk 00:45:08]} {[%emt 00:00:11]} c5 {[%clk 00:45:12]} {[%emt 00:00:08]}. Is there any style which let me control how much time information should be displayed? Thanks for any help

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a minimal working example of what you tried so far?
